# Tracking adwords performance on a site using Backbone Router

Tags: backbone.js, google-analytics, google-ads-api

So we just relaunched our site as a Backbone powered single-paged app, but we're having a heck of a time tracking our conversions from our AdWords ads into the site with Google Analytics.

The problem is that in order for Google Analytics to track the fact that the user came in from AdWords, it looks for a URL query parameter called `gclid` in the URL:

```
http://test.com/?gclid=(Q#kjsdf0INKJSDJF9
```

But, when the Router from Backbone initializes, it removes all the query parameters from the URL, so when the tracking event fires, it doesn't see that the user came from an AdWords ad.

We tried sending the user to an interstitial page that loads the analytics code and waits for the event to fire and then forwards them into the site, but

1. Its ugly and shows users a blank page for a while
2. Doesn't work without a significant wait for IE8 users (who make up 50% of our user base sadly)

We contacted Google's AdWords help to see if we can manually give the `gclid` to Analytics and their answer was

> You should hire one of our consultants who will figure out how to keep the URL parameters on your site so it works correctly because we do not support manually setting the `gclid` ID

(Sadly only a very minor paraphrase.)

Google-fu leaves me blank in this respect -- lots of people asking questions in the Google forums, but no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how everything is setup, but Backbone might not be seeing that URL with the parameters as a match, or a route that it knows about. In fact, you can test that by doing something like...

```
unless Backbone.history.start(pushState: true)
  window.location = someDefaultURL;
```

If you wanted just a simple way to match routes with params, here's two ways that you could do it.

```
class MyRouter extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    'test?*params': 'test'
    'testTwo?gclid=:gclid': 'testTwo'

  test: (params) ->
    console.log 'test route', params

  testTwo: (gclid) ->
    console.log 'test route two', gclid
```

Comment: The problem isn't getting the URL query params, but rather keeping them in the URL.  Since Google Analytics is asynchronous I can't control when it fires the tracking event, so they need to be present until after the event fires.

Comment: Ah, ok oops. Sorry I didn't catch that part at first.

Comment: No, you were right. I'm partially an idiot. The URL param disappears when you call `navigate` with your path. So I need to make it append the query params to navigate if present. But make it so the query params come BEFORE the hash in IE. FUN!

Comment: I'm not sure then, sorry. Doing some tests locally and Backbone doesn't strip the query params from the URL for me.

Comment: Yeah, just stepped through the entire transaction in the debugger and watched the URL. Argh. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here is that I was immediately pushing an entry into the history object with the `navigate` method.

This overwrites (correctly) the current URL and does not preserve URL parameters (although it would be nice if it could, I guess that's a pull request I should make).

By not calling `navigate` immediately this allows the URL parameter to stay in the URL long enough for G.A. to see it.